# SHGetImageList - SHIL_JUMBO for smaller icons (32,32)

Tags: c#, windows-vista, icons

In my code I get a list of images through the function SHGETImageList with size SHIL_JUMBO.

```
 IImageList iml;
 var hres = SHGetImageList(SHIL_JUMBO, ref iidImageList, out  iml);
 IntPtr hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
 iml.GetIcon(i, ILD_TRANSPARENT |  ILD_IMAGE, ref hIcon);

 Icon ico =  (Icon)System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(hIcon).Clone();
 ShellAPI.DestroyIcon(hIcon);
```

Everything is ok, but when it has to get smaller icons (when they don't have a size for 256x256) the function GetIcon returns me an icon with the size of 256x256 but with the icon of size 32x32 in top left corner. I want to resize this icon to the new size (256 x 256).

I don't have any information how to have the system resize my icon to 256 x 256. Every function in iml (like GetImageInfo, GetImageRect) for this size returns an empty structure.

It's possible to get information that this icon is smaller and i can get icon from another source.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Driving me nuts.  Attacking the problem from the other direction: Is there a way to detect if there IS a Jumbo Icon or not ?

Comment: What value of i gives you this? Are you sure it's not because they are simply overlay images?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like, since Vista, Microsoft expects developers to rely on `IShellItem` and `IShellItemImageFactory` interfaces. Unlike `IImageList` implementation of the system image lists, which is badly broken (most methods fail with `E_NOTIMPL`, icon sizes are not reported), `IShellItemImageFactory` produces images exactly like they are displayed in Explorer. In case of small icons requested in "jumbo" size, they are centered and surrounded by a border (on Windows 7, at least). While it is less efficient and more memory consuming to use than `IImageList`, Explorer probably uses it too, so it's no big deal.

See [IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

There's a library for .NET which supports these interfaces: [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack).

---

While this doesn't exactly answer your question (there's still no reliable way to determine size of icons), I think resizing a small 32x32 icon to 256x256 is a bad idea, and Explorer way (resizing only up to 48x48, then centering) should be preffered. This will also provide a consistent behavior which is a good idea.

Considering questions like this have been posted in many places, and none have been answered for years, I'm afraid more information can only be obtained by reverse-engineering Windows Shell, and in particular standard/default `IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage` implementation. [Geoff Chappell](http://www.geoffchappell.com/) did quite a bit of reverse engineering of shell, so maybe it's worth trying to ask him...

Comment: This answer has a good wrapper for GetImage method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21752100/242451

Answer (score 0):

You could execute some code to identify the image metrics and use the following when required:

`var hres = SHGetImageList(SHIL_LARGE, ref iidImageList, out  iml);`

SHIL_LARGE is for 32x32.

The IImageList pointer type, such as that returned in the ppv parameter, can be cast as an HIMAGELIST as needed; for example, for use in a list view. Conversely, an HIMAGELIST can be cast as a pointer to an IImageList.
As of Windows Vista, SHIL_SMALL, **SHIL_LARGE**, and SHIL_EXTRALARGE **scale** with dots per inch (dpi) *if the process is marked as dpi-aware*. To set these types to be dpi-aware, call SetProcessDPIAware. SHIL_JUMBO is fixed at 256 pixels regardless of the dpi-aware setting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762185(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

I have run your example using

```
const string IID_IImageList = "46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950";
const string IID_IImageList2 = "192B9D83-50FC-457B-90A0-2B82A8B5DAE1";
```

defined in CommonControls.h
Upon running:

```
        IEnumerable<int> shils =  new int[]{ 
            ShellAPI.SHIL_EXTRALARGE, 
            ShellAPI.SHIL_JUMBO, 
            ShellAPI.SHIL_SYSSMALL,
            ShellAPI.SHIL_LARGE, 
            ShellAPI.SHIL_SMALL,
            ShellAPI.SHIL_LAST
        };
        ShellAPI.IImageList ppv = null;
        Guid guil = new Guid(IID_IImageList2);//or IID_IImageList
        foreach (int iil in shils)
        {
            ShellAPI.SHGetImageList(iil, ref guil, ref ppv);
            int noImages = 0;
            ppv.GetImageCount(ref noImages);
            //...
        }
```

the images count stays constant. Therefore I must disagree with

> when they don't have a size for 256x256

For every image list type there's a constant number of images, so no icons missing for the jumbo setting.

I have persisted all found icons with all resolutions (16x16,32x32,48x48,256x256). 
The aspect ratio is identical between all different sizes of the same icon (same image list index/different resolution). Aspect ratio means that the 256x256 version is not the 48x48 version pasted in a corner, and the rest black background padding.

Moreover, all the

> icons with the size of 256x256 but with the icon of size 32x32 in top left corner
>   are in fact overlay images, as one can check:

```
int currentImageListIndex; //loop by noImages above
int idx0Based=0;
ppv.GetOverlayImage(currentImageListIndex+1, ref idx0Based);
```

Quality degradation can be easily found out using IImageAList::GetItemFlags and checking the output dwFlags parameter for ILIF_LOWQUALITY, msdn quote below

> Windows Vista and later. Indicates that the item in the imagelist was generated via a StretchBlt function, consequently image quality may have degraded