# Extract thumbnail for any file in Windows C#

Tags: c#, .net, thumbnails

I need to extract a thumbnail for uploaded files like ppt, word files, images etc. I have implemented this ([Extract thumbnail for any file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751747/extract-thumbnail-for-any-file-in-windows)) answer but I am getting files with black background. On one machine it works on other it gives thumbnail with black background.
[image: Sample of thumbnail image obtained]

Comment: This has already been answered
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751747/extract-thumbnail-for-any-file-in-windows

Comment: @abhijithkarkal Thanks for the reply, I have already used that approach as stated in my question. Also my requirements changed so no longer need this but we will keep this open to help others and for future reference...cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is possible. For what i know pictureboxes don't support .ico files, so you would have to convert the icon to a supported format.

Comment: I will try to figure it out for you.