# How to get thumbnail of RTF file

Tags: c#

How can I get thumbnail of RTF file in C#? It's difficult because RTF file is not an image file. I've searched on the Internet but have found nothing.

Comment: Pussible duplicate [Extract thumbnail for any file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21751747/375958)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract thumbnail for any file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751747/extract-thumbnail-for-any-file-in-windows)