# Can't get thumbnail from IShellItem using IThumbnailProvider

Tags: file, winapi, rust, thumbnails, windows-shell

So I've written some code to get the thumbnail from a file using a file path string as an input. First I get the IShellItem at the location, then get the IThumbnailProvider, and now I'm trying to get the thumbnail from the ThumbnailProvider.

```rs
unsafe {
    CoInitialize(None).expect("Failed to initialize COM");

    let item: IShellItem = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(
        w!("J:\\Apps\\Dolphin-x64\\Dolphin.exe"),
        None
    ).expect("Failed to get shell item");

    let thumb_provider: IThumbnailProvider = item
        .BindToHandler(None, &BHID_ThumbnailHandler)
        .expect("Failed to get thumbnail provider");

    let mut icon_bitmap_ref = MaybeUninit::<HBITMAP>::uninit();

    let mut alpha_type = MaybeUninit::<WTS_ALPHATYPE>::uninit();

    let mut icon_bitmap = MaybeUninit::<BITMAP>::uninit();

    thumb_provider
        .GetThumbnail(96, icon_bitmap_ref.as_mut_ptr(), alpha_type.as_mut_ptr())
        .expect("Failed to get thumbnail");
    // Errors right after this

    match
        GetObjectW(
            icon_bitmap_ref.assume_init(),
            std::mem::size_of::<BITMAP>() as i32,
            Some(icon_bitmap.as_mut_ptr().cast())
        )
    {
        0 => panic!("Failed to get bitmap"),
        _ => {
            let icon_image = match alpha_type.assume_init() {
                WTSAT_UNKNOWN => bitmap_to_image(icon_bitmap.assume_init(), true),
                WTSAT_RGB => bitmap_to_image(icon_bitmap.assume_init(), false),
                WTSAT_ARGB => bitmap_to_image(icon_bitmap.assume_init(), true),
                _ => unreachable!("Unknown alpha type"),
            };

            icon_image.save("icon.png").expect("Failed to save icon");
        }
    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

But every time I try and run it, it returns this error

```rs
Failed to get thumbnail provider: Error { code: HRESULT(0x80004001), message: "Not implemented" }
```

I honestly wouldn't be surprised if it's just a memory issue, since I've never programmed in C or C++, and I'm very new to win32 and low level rust, but the error message isn't helpful whatsoever, and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. There is no thumbnail provider for the file. Makes sense, as an EXE file is not an image file. In any case, per the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751747/extract-thumbnail-for-any-file-in-windows), try querying the `IShellItem` for `IShellItemImageFactory` and if successful then call it's `GetImage()` method.

Comment: You can get `IShellItemImageFactory` directly from `SHCreateItemFromParsingName`

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, your destructors run *after* the `CoUninitialize()` call. Best not to call `CoUninitialize()` at all.

Comment: Thanks, getting an IShellItemImageFactory directory from the SHCreateItemFromParsingName function worked. I did also remove the CoUninitialize call, as I assume it's kind of pointless to run it when the program ends, since it doesn't really matter what happens after the program terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RemyLebeau said, there is [no thumbnail provider](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/UsingThumbnailProviders) for the executable file.

While the [IShellItemImageFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitemimagefactory) interface

> Exposes a method to return either icons or thumbnails for Shell items.
> If no thumbnail or icon is available for the requested item, a
> per-class icon may be provided from the Shell.

A full example [Using Image Factory](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/UsingImageFactory).